# Would a compiled program have different machine codes when executed on PC, Mac, Linux etc?

Tags: compilation, cross-platform, machine-code

I'm just getting started learning the very fundamentals of computers and programming. I've grasped that, in compiled programs, the machine code generated is specific to the type of processors and their instruction sets. What I'd like to know is, say, I have Windows, OS X and Linux all running on the exact same hardware (processor to be specific), would the machine code generated from this compiled program differ across the OSes? Is machine code OS dependent or will it be an exact same copy of bits and bytes across all the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened when you tried it?  As answered the file formats supported may vary, but you asked about machine code.

The machine code for the same processor core is the same of course.  But only some percentage of the code is generic

```
a=b+c:
printf("%u\n",a);
```

Assume even you are using the same compiler version targeted at the same cpu but with a different operating system (same computer running linux then later windows) the addition is ideally the same assuming the top level function/source code is the same.

First off the entry point of the code may vary from one OS to another, so the linker may make the program different, for position dependent code, fixed addresses will end up in the binary, you can call that machine code or not, but the specific addresses may result in different instructions.  A branch/jump may have to be encoded differently based on the address of course, but in one system you may have one form of branch another may require a trampoline to get from one place to another.

Then there are the system calls themselves, no reason to assume that the system calls between operating systems are the same.  This can make the code vary in size, etc which can again cause the compiler or linker to have to make different machine code choices based on how near or far a jmp target is for some instruction sets or can the address be encoded as an immediate or do you have to load it from a nearby location then branch to that indirectly.

EDIT

Long before you start to ponder/worry about what happens on different operating systems on the same platform or target.  Understand the basics of putting a program together, and what kinds of things can change the machine code.

A very simple program/function

```
extern unsigned int dummy ( unsigned int );
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    dummy(a+b+3);
    return(a+b+7);
}
```

compile then disassemble

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e0804001    add r4, r0, r1
   8:   e2840003    add r0, r4, #3
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <dummy>
  10:   e2840007    add r0, r4, #7
  14:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

There is actually a ton of stuff going on there.  This is arm, full sized (not thumb...yet).  The a parameter comes in in r0, b in r1, result out in r0.  lr is the return address register basically, so if we are calling another function we need to save that (on the stack) likewise we are going to re-use r0 to call dummy and in fact with this calling convention any function can modify/destroy r0-r3, so the compiler is going to need to deal with our two parameters, since I intentionally used them in the same way the compiler can optimize a+b into a register and save that on the stack, actually for performance reasons no doubt, they save r4 on the stack and then use r4 to save a+b, you cannot modify r4 at will in a function based on the calling convention so any nested function would have to preserve it and return with it in the as found state, so it is safe to just leave a+b there when calling other functions.

They add 3 to our a+b sum in r4 and call dummy.  When it returns they add 7 to the a+b sum in r4 and return in r0.

From a machine code perspective this is not yet linked and dummy is an external function

```
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <dummy>
```

I call it dummy because when we use it here in a second it does nothing but return, a dummy function.  The instruction encoded there is clearly wrong branching to the beginning of fun would not work that is recursion that is not what we asked for.  So lets link it, at a minimum we need to declare a _start label to make the gnu linker happy, but I want to do more than that:

```
.globl _start
_start
    bl fun
    b .

.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

and linking for an entry address of 0x1000 produced this

```
00001000 <_start>:
    1000:   eb000001    bl  100c <fun>
    1004:   eafffffe    b   1004 <_start+0x4>

00001008 <dummy>:
    1008:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000100c <fun>:
    100c:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
    1010:   e0804001    add r4, r0, r1
    1014:   e2840003    add r0, r4, #3
    1018:   ebfffffa    bl  1008 <dummy>
    101c:   e2840007    add r0, r4, #7
    1020:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
    1024:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

The linker filled in the address for dummy by modifying the instruction that calls it, so you can see that the machine code has changed.

```
    1018:   ebfffffa    bl  1008 <dummy>
```

Depending on how far away things are or other factors can change this, the bl instruction here has a long range but not the full address space, so if the program is sufficiently large and there is  a lot of code between the caller and the callee then the linker may have to do more work.  For different reasons I can cause that.  Arm has arm and thumb modes and you have to use specific instructions in order to switch, bl not being one of them (or at least not for all of the arms).

If I add these two lines in front of the dummy function

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

Forcing the assembler to generate thumb instructions and mark the dummy label as a thumb label then

```
00001000 <_start>:
    1000:   eb000001    bl  100c <fun>
    1004:   eafffffe    b   1004 <_start+0x4>

00001008 <dummy>:
    1008:   4770        bx  lr
    100a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

0000100c <fun>:
    100c:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
    1010:   e0804001    add r4, r0, r1
    1014:   e2840003    add r0, r4, #3
    1018:   eb000002    bl  1028 <__dummy_from_arm>
    101c:   e2840007    add r0, r4, #7
    1020:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
    1024:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00001028 <__dummy_from_arm>:
    1028:   e59fc000    ldr r12, [pc]   ; 1030 <__dummy_from_arm+0x8>
    102c:   e12fff1c    bx  r12
    1030:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9
    1034:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Because the BX is required to switch modes in this case and fun is arm mode and dummy is thumb mode the linker has very nicely for us added a trampoline function I call it to bounce off of to get from fun to dummy.  The link register (lr) contains a bit that tells the bx on the return which mode to switch to so there is no extra work there to modify the dummy function.

Had there have been a great distance between the two functions in memory I would hope the linker would have also patched that up for us, but you never know until you try.

```
.globl _start
_start:
    bl fun
    b .


.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr


.space 0x10000000
```

sigh, oh well

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x1000 v.o so.o -o so.elf
v.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_ARM_CALL against symbol `fun' defined in .text section in so.o
```

if we change one plus to a minus:

```
extern unsigned int dummy ( unsigned int );
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    dummy(a-b+3);
    return(a+b+7);
}
```

and it gets more complicated

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   4:   e1a04001    mov r4, r1
   8:   e1a05000    mov r5, r0
   c:   e0400001    sub r0, r0, r1
  10:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
  14:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <dummy>
  18:   e2840007    add r0, r4, #7
  1c:   e0800005    add r0, r0, r5
  20:   e8bd4070    pop {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

they can no longer optimize the a+b result so more stack space or in the case of this optimizer, save other things on the stack to make room in registers.  Now you ask why is r6 pushed on the stack?  It is not being modified?  This abi requires a 64 bit aligned stack so that means pushing four registers to save three things or push the three things and then modify the stack pointer, for this instruction set pushing the four things is cheaper than fetching another instruction and executing it.

if for whatever reason the external function becomes local

```
void dummy ( unsigned int )
{
}
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    dummy(a-b+3);
    return(a+b+7);
}
```

that changes things again

```
00000000 <dummy>:
   0:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000004 <fun>:
   4:   e2811007    add r1, r1, #7
   8:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Since dummy doesnt use the parameter passed and the optimizer can now see it, then there is no reason to waste instructions subtracting and adding 3, that is all dead code, so remove it.  We are no longer calling dummy since it is dead code so no need to save the link register on the stack and save the parameters just do the addition and return.

```
static void dummy ( unsigned int x )
{
}
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    dummy(a-b+3);
    return(a+b+7);
}
```

making dummy local/static and nobody using it

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2811007    add r1, r1, #7
   4:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

last experiment

```
static unsigned int dummy ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+1);
}
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int c;
    c=dummy(a-b+3);
    return(a+b+c);
}
```

dummy is static and called, but it is optimized here to be inline, so there is no call to it, so neither external folks can use it (static) nor does anyone inside this file use it, so there is no reason to generate it.

The compiler examines all of the operations and optimizes it.  a-b+3+1+a+b = a+a+4 = (2*a)+4 = (a<<1)+4;
Why did they use a shift left instead of just add r0,r0,r0, dont know maybe the shift is faster in the pipe, or maybe it is irrelevant and either one was just as good and the compiler author chose this method, or perhaps the internal code which is somewhat generic figured this out and before it went to the backend it had been converted into a shift rather than an add.

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e1a00080    lsl r0, r0, #1
   4:   e2800004    add r0, r0, #4
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

command lines used for these experiments

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -O2 so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-as v.s -o v.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x1000 v.o so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf
```

The point being you can do these kinds of simple experiments yourself and begin to understand what is going on when and where the compiler and linker makes modifications to the machine code if that is how you like to think of it.  And then realize which I sorta showed here when I added the non-static dummy function (the fun() function now was pushed deeper into memory) as you add more code, for example a C library from one operating system to the next may change or may be mostly identical except for the system calls so they may vary in size causing other code to possibly be moved around a larger puts() might cause printf() to live at a different address all other factors held constant.  If not liking statically then no doubt there will be differences, just the file format and mechanism used to find a .so file on linux or a .dll on windows parse it, connect the dots runtime between the system calls in the application to the shared libraries.  The file format and the location of shared libraries by themselves in application space will cause the binary that is linked with the operating specific stub to be different.  And then eventually the actual system call itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, in effect, the machine code is not only processor dependent, but also dependent on the platform OS (the system calls, the compiler program, the linker program, etc), all of which play a role in how similar or different the final machine code will look on paper?

Comment: yes everything plays a role in how the program is constructed.  Even if everything else were identical the system calls themselves would expect to vary from one operating system to another, basically the exact mechanism/instructions used for the application layer to communicate with the kernel layer.  So you would have those differences.

Comment: If you are asking if the instruction set is the same, yes, assuming the same processor(s) the instruction set is the same.  Just like a biology text book in english and a social studies text book in english use the same english alphabet.

Comment: Thanks for the big picture. This is seriously beyond me, for a beginner such as myself. But I've tried to reiterate the answer few times and now I understand well that everything can affect the end result machine code and it's not what I should be concerned most about :)

Comment: This is the idea behind the C language and JAVA and Python, etc...Making a language that is ideally independent of the cpu.  C was and still is a good language, but we use guis now for a lot of things and you get gui call specific which is often operating system specific and the code doesnt port so well, thus JAVA and Python and some others.  And they have had better success in directly porting across platforms.

Comment: The key is not the machine code, but the high level language and the ability to compile or interpret that language on the target (which all of those are target specific something about the compiler or interpreter or virtual machine) such that the higher level ports hopefully without modification.

Comment: take A pc and run windows, linux and a hackintosh on it and it is the same machine, same instruction set that the processor uses, but the binaries themselves generally dont port, because the cpu is not the only factor...

Answer (score 1):

Binaries are generally not portable across systems. Linux (and Unix) use [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable format, macOS uses [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) and Windows uses [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

Comment: Thanks for the info on the binaries. It helped me understand a part of it. I was particularly interested in the result of machine code as noted by @old_timer